# Publish existing repo

Tags: git

Here I am again with my week-old repo, and getting worried that my development computer will fall to the swimming pool. Now I want to send my local repo to the host where I hold my bare repositories, and I have to do, *again*, the following:

```
git clone --bare my-repo my-repo.git
ssh git@myserver "mkdir /opt/git/placeholder-dir"
scp -r my-repo.git git@myserver:/opt/git/praceholder-dir
cd my-repo
git add remote origin myserver-blah-blah
```

Isn't there a better (shorter, easier, less error-prone) way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a remote repo for backup and push all branches and tags to it:

```
ssh git@myserver "git init --bare /opt/git/placeholder-dir"
git add remote backup myserver-blah-blah
```

When you need to backup your local repo

```
git push backup --all
git push backup --tags
```

changes that you have stashed will not be pushed to backup

Answer (score 3):

You're doing some unnecessary work.  I would just run:

```
ssh git@myserver git init --bare /opt/git/placeholder-dir
```

And then, from inside your `my-repo` directory:

```
git add remote origin git@myserver:placeholder-dir
git push origin master
```

That seems much easier.

**Update**

If you're the *only* person pushing to your remote server, you could stick the following in a script called, say, `gitwrapper`:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" ] || exit 1

eval set -- $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND

# if this script is triggered by a push operation
if [ "$1" = "git-receive-pack" ] ; then
    if [[ "$2" == */* ]]; then
            echo "*** Repository names must not contain '/'" >&2
            exit 1
    fi

    if [[ "$2" == .* ]]; then
            echo "*** Repository names must not start with '.'" >&2
            exit 1
    fi

    if [[ "$2" != *.git ]]; then
            echo "*** Repository names must end with '.git'" >&2
            exit 1
    fi

    if ! [ -d "$2" ]; then
            echo "Creating repository $2" >&2
            git init --bare "$2" >&2
    fi
fi

exec "$@"
```

And then in your `ssh_config` file, specify the `command=` option:

```
command="/home/git/bin/gitwrapper" ssh-rsa AAAA...
```

(Replacing `/home/git/bin/gitwrapper` with the actual path to the
`gitwrapper` script).

This script will automatically create a target repository if it
doesn't already exist.  So I can do something like this:

```
$ git push git@localhost:myrepo.git
```

And see:

```
Creating repository myrepo.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/git/myrepo.git/
Counting objects: 301, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (290/290), done.
Writing objects: 100% (301/301), 159.68 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 301 (delta 156), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@localhost:myrepo.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Note in particular the first two lines of that output.  Of course,
spelling mistakes are a problem:

```
$ git push git@localhost:mtrepo.git
```

Oops.

Hopefully it goes without saying, but if *anybody* other than you is
pushing to your remote server this script would be a terrible,
horrible idea. It doesn't do any path checking, so it will happily
create repositories anywhere the target user has write access.  It
may even allow arbitrary command execution.